# How to switch user using Spring in Java for testing purposes?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

I wrote functionality using Spring Security `SwitchUserFilter`. In application I can switch user using `/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=xxx` URL and go back to previous using `/j_spring_security_exit_user`.
I also implemented several methods that depends on fact of switching user, so I want to write unit tests for them.
Therefore my question is how can I switch user in jUnit tests environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote method which is preparing user with `SwitchUserGrantedAuthority` and log him in. It seems working fine for my testing purposes, but any tips and comments would be very appreciated.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private User logAdminAsUser(User admin, String roleName) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
        new TestingAuthenticationToken(admin, null, "ROLE_ADMIN"));
    Authentication adminAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    SwitchUserGrantedAuthority switchUserGrantedAuthority =
        new SwitchUserGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", adminAuth);
    List authorities = new LinkedList();
    authorities.add(switchUserGrantedAuthority);
    User user = populator.storeUser("ROLE_USER");
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
        new TestingAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities));
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an integrational test, you should consider using a custom http client, or if your test logic depends on it, even GUI drivers like Selenium.

If we are talking about unit tests, refer to Springs 
http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/07/preview-spring-security-test-method-security
documentation, they support testing heavily, @WithMockUser annotation appears to be what you are looking for, it allows you to specify with which role or user this test should be runned.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really useful. Eventually I solved it by preparing user with `SwitchGrantedAuthority` what wasn't that difficult as I thought. I will place my anwer here later today if you are interested.

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to see your solution, please.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
private void switchUser(User user, String roleName) 
{
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = 
            new ArrayList<>();
    GrantedAuthority ga = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName);
    authorities.add(ga);

    Authentication result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokenExt(
            user,
            authentication.getCredentials(),
            null,
            System.currentTimeMillis()
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( result );
}
```

where `User` is the new user, and the `roleName` is the new authority to set (of course this method can be modified get more params, etc.)